# Dataloader.io Importing numbers with extra zeros

Tags: formatting, dataloader.io

While trying to import/update some Contract records in my Salesforce system, I have run into issues with the formatting and consistency of currency fields.

If I update a currency field with the value 67539,00 then it appears in Salesforce as 6,753,900.00 (i.e. the figure gets multiplied by 100).

**Why is this happening? How can I correct this?**

Notes:

- The locale for the system & user is set to English (United States)
- The value is formatted as text in my .csv file
- I need Salesforce recognise the commas as decimal places, but it refuses to do so.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer:
You need to replace the commas in your import file with periods. You should be able to accomplish this rather easily in Excel using a formula.

Once done, save the file as a CSV and import into salesforce. Now 67539.00 will be imported correctly.

There may be another way but in US currency, commas are not used to seperate the decimals from the whole number. The number 100,700 is actually 100170, not 100.700

in my opinion it is just easier to clean the CSV file before importing.